# Divide a matrix into small matrices with equal number of columns using for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix with size 1*92609 . I want to loop the matrix and take 8 values at a time to perform element wise multiplication with another 8 bit size matrix. Either, what i want to do is divide the matrix, such that in the first iteration only the first 1:8 elements are taken, and, in second iteration, 8:16 elements are taken and so on.

How can I achieve this in matlab using "for" loop. Here, is the screen shot of the matrix.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is `MTX` you could do something like

```
N = numel(MTX)
for k = 1:8:N
   subMtx = MTX(k:min(k+7,N));
   do your processing with subMtx
end
```

The expression `1:8:N` gives the sequence `1, 9, 17, ...`.
The `min(k+7,N)` is necessary because the matrix size (92609) is not divisible by 8. Beware that the last sub-matrix has only one element.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**x** is your original array and you want take mean of each 8 elements

```
n = floor( length(x)/8 );       % how many series of 8 elements in x
y = zeros( 1,n );               % preallocate
k = 0;                          % counter for y array
for i = 1:8:length(x)-1
    k = k + 1;
    y(k) = mean( x(i:i+7) );    % take mean of each 8 elements
end
```

Comment: `x(i+7)` might not exist, see the other answer.

Comment: Pay attention to this line

    `for i = 1:8:length(x)`

'**i**' cannot be bigger than length(x)-8

Comment: Okay. You are right. Should be: 
 `for i = 1:8:length(x)-1`

Comment: Should be `8*n`. Or loop over `k=1:n` instead.

Comment: You’re aware that you can [edit] your answer to correct it? These comments could be deleted, leaving a not-completely-correct answer here!

Comment: Yes i can do it. THanks bro